# Resharper take all settings from team-shared or default

Tags: c#, resharper

We're setting up an environment, where developers of three companies (~25 people) will work in the same GIT repo on a ASP.NET WebAPI application and we want to enforce the coding guidelines across the entire team with a team-shared resharper configuration.

Is there a magic switch somewhere to not use the pretty complex [sharing configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Sharing_Configuration_Options.html) and to reduce it to: use team-shared and if the property is not explicitly configured, use defaults?

It is espetially important for the silent code cleanup which has been configured and is being triggered on every file save with the [ReSharperAutoFormatOnSave](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PedroPombeiro.ReSharperAutoFormatOnSave) extension.